# EF6.2 was restored using .netFramework version 4.6.1 instead of the project target framework .NETStandard v2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-standard-2.0

I created a brand new .NETStandard project library and the target framework is  the .NETStandard v2.0

I installed Entity Framework 6.2 but I'm getting the error indicating that this package may not be fully compatible with your project.

When I'm trying to update packages, I'm getting this:

> Package 'EntityFramework 6.0' was restored using '.NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'

Are there anything I can do to solved this problem? or There is no way to use Entity Framework 6.2 (6.1.3) in a .NETStandard 2.0 project ?

I'm using VS2017

[image]

Answer (score 3):

EF6 is not fully compatible with .NETStandard, so you should use EF Core in .NETStandard projects.

But if you only use that project in .NETFramework, it will work, but it may not work in other frameworks (.NETCore, Xamarin).